# C writing in files problems with repeatable choice

Tags: c, arrays, string, variables, structure

Ok, thats half of my code, but i have problem and i cant fix it. For example i need to pick choice 2 it is adding something to file, i enter[ name, surname, date, gender ] press enter and program shows like menu again(2.Add to file) but this time automatically picks 2 choice and i need to write data another time and it happens  all the time when picking choice 2. Please help me find solution of this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define N 15


 struct date
    { int da_year;
      int da_month;
      int da_day;
    };

    struct studenti
    {
      int Nr;
      char name[25];
      char surname[25];
      struct date dzd;
      char dzimums; 
    }students[N] ;


    int main()
    {

    sakums:    

      // FILE *fails_st;
       char line[100];
       char *ptk; char * end; int i;int sorted;
        int g=0,ch,count=0;
        int n;
        int choice;




       FILE *fails_st = fopen("studenti.txt", "r+");
       /* errors ja neizdodas atveert failu  */
        if (fails_st == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening file!\n");
            exit(1);
        }




        printf("\n2.Add to file");   
     scanf("%d",&choice); 





if(choice==2){

     /* write in file */     
     for (n=0; n<1; n++)
        {
        printf("%d. Ievadiet: vards, uzvards, datums, dzimums >", n+1);
        scanf("%s",&students[n].name);
        scanf("%s",&students[n].surname);
        scanf("%d.%d.%d",  &students[n].dzd.da_day, &students[n].dzd.da_month,             &students[n].dzd.da_year);
        scanf("%c",&students[n].dzimums);

        }    
    fseek(fails_st, 0, SEEK_END); 
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    fprintf(fails_st, " %d. %s %s %d.%d.%d %c\n", N+1, students[i].name, 
              students[i].surname, students[i].dzd.da_day, 
              students[i].dzd.da_month, students[i].dzd.da_year, 
              students[i].dzimums); 

                  fclose(fails_st); 
                  goto sakums; 

    }




       getche();                 
       return 0;

}
```

Comment: `GOTO` ? My eyes - they burn !!!!

Comment: @John3136 my eyes melt from all of the blinding whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely that `scanf` happily does nothing if the format string that is its first parameter doesn't match the available input. That means it won't change the value of `choice`, so it will still be 2.

The cause of this is probably that what you input doesn't match your format strings. You can detect when this happens by checking the return value of `scanf` - it will return the number of variables written to, basically. If that is less than the number of format specifiers in your format string, something went wrong.

At that point, you probably want to consume all the available input (maybe something like `int c; do { c = getchar(); } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);` for a simple program like yours) and then prompt the user again.

In particular, I believe your `scanf("%c", ...)` is likely the culprit: `%c`, unlike most `scanf` specifiers, will not ignore leading whitespace, but accept any character. So if you typed in "firstname lastname 1980.6.11 f", for example, the previous `scanf` call will just have consumed "6.11.1980", leaving " f" in the input buffer (note the space). Then the `scanf` with `%c` will read the space into the gender field, and leave the "f" in the input buffer. On the next go around, `scanf("%d",&choice);` will not do anything because "f" is not a valid number, `choice` will remain 2 and the "f" will get read as the first name on the next student entry, further confusing matters...

The solution is, I believe, to use `scanf(" %c", ...);` to explicitly consume leading whitespace.